# Read it out vs read out

Tags: grammar, verbs

I was reading him a story.

I wanted him to read out the sentence after I read.

> "Read it out"
>
> "Read out."

Can pronoun ommit after "read"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be omitted. But we usually read *out loud* when others could hear what you are saying.

> Read it out loud.
>   Read out loud.

The second example is more of a command than the first one.

Answer (score 2):

No, just "**read out**" on its own makes no sense.  "**Read out**" is a phrasal verb that requires an object - unlike "**read**" (which can be intransitive).

You can instruct someone to "**read**" without specifying an object pronoun (or any object), but you can't say "**read out**" without specifying a pronoun.

You can say:

> Read.
>
> Read aloud.
>
> Read out loud.

This is OK because here, "**out loud**" is an adverbial phrase meaning "**aloud**", whereas in the phrase "**read it out**", you're using the phrasal verb "**read out"** *+ object*.

Also valid:

> Read quietly.
>
> Read to yourself.
>
> Read slowly.
>
> Read faster.
>
> Read carefully.
>
> Read it.
>
> Read it out.
>
> Read it out slowly.

Etc.